# Servidor de aplicação Web fora do ar e aplicação cliente assume posição

Tags: apache, aplicação-web, wildfly, internet

Gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de uma aplicação cliente assumir quando o servidor está fora do ar, como se fosse um Dropbox, por exemplo, você pode colocar um arquivo, ou um diretório dentro das pastas que são sincronizadas através do programa (Dropbox) e a mesma só será sincronizada quando o computador estiver conectado na Internet ou quando o servidor do Dropbox voltar ao ar. Porém falando agora em aplicação Web, tem como fazer isso? A Internet caiu ou o servidor ficou fora, na próxima requisição em que a conexão não deu sinal de retorno do servidor irá redicionar para uma página web ou algum recurso no browser dentro da próprio computador onde o usuário pode fazer determinada operação, assim que for reestabelecida a conexão os dados do cliente serão sincronizados com o servidor sem perder nenhuma informação e o usuário perceber que a conexão com o site caiu.

Comment: Analise o tipo de aplicação antes de fazer. Isso não é trivial e geralmente se faz esse tipo de coisa quando não há concorrencia de 'usuários' na alteração de dados. Você também teria de implementar algum tipo de controle sobre quais dados foram alterados por usuários que não perderam a conexão e isso não é tão trivial na maioria dos casos. Enfim, links de redundância ou estratégias de cluster de servidores costumam ser mais seguros e com custo de implementação mais rápido e menos complexo.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta @Intruso, levarei em consideração na hora de escolher a melhor arquitetura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe maneira sim, a partir do html 5 existe uma especificação própria para offline app, além disso existem várias apis que facilitam o cache de resources para assumir quando o servidor por algum motivo estiver offline.
Apesar de tudo, este trabalho não é trivial, nada é feito de forma "automática".
Vou lhe deixar alguns links para que possa conferir.

Especificação de páginas offline: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html
Artigo muito bom sobre o assunto: http://diveintohtml5.com.br/offline.html

Até aqui está solucionado o problema das páginas offline, além disso, você precisará guardar os dados com as alterações do usuário para posteriormente transmitir para o servidor, na especificação html 5 existem 2 alternativas, Web Sql Database e Web Storage.

No caso de Web Sql Db, é basicamente um banco de dados Sqlite, ou seja, com funções mínimas de persistência, que o próprio navegador oferta, você pode ver um exemplo de como utilizá-lo aqui: http://elemarjr.net/2010/10/19/html-5-parte-6-armazendando-dados-com-web-sql-databases/

Quanto ao web storage, é algo como um mapa de chave e valor local também ofertado pelo navegador, é quase um cookie mas que não é enviado para o servidor, você pode ver mais informações sobre como utilizá-lo aqui: http://elemarjr.net/2010/10/18/html-5-parte-5-armazenando-dados-com-web-storage/

Comment: Obrigado, dessa maneira então seria limitado então? A minha ideia é que deveria salvar os dados em um banco de dados temporário e fazer a sincronização com o servidor depois.

Comment: Muito bom o segundo artigo. Deu até uma ideia para resolver uma situação num site meu, que é o de apresentar uma página no estilo offline.

Comment: Os navegadores atualmente vem com um "banco de dados" sqlite local, você pode salvar os dados nele e sincronizar posteriormente.

Comment: Teria como colocar uma resposta sobre isso @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria? Agradeço desde já. Encontrei algo sobre o que você falou: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200976/sqlite-in-chrome.

Comment: Obrigado pela edição em sua resposta @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria, agora resta saber como sincronizar com o servidor remoto, mas acredito que é questão para uma outra pergunta.

Comment: A parte da sincronização é algo que tem que ser implementado manualmente, uma vez que perceba que o servidor está online novamente, você checa se houve alterações do usuário e as envia em background para o servidor. Infelizmente não existe especificação para esta parte.